# zend framework 2 out of the box modular system

Tags: zend-framework2, modularity

I want to make a modular CMS in Zend Framework 2 . Like News module , Gallery module and etc...
How to make independent module in zf2 ? My biggest challenge in this case is configuring other modules like Zfcadmin and BjyAuthorize modules.
How Can I set all configurations in my own module ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can config other modules in your module. For example you can add child route of ZfcAdmin in your news module . There is no obligation to configure each module in its module.config.php file. Remember modules are just namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely have a look at [ensemble](http://ensemble.github.com) if you want to develop your own CMS. Ensemble is built on top of ZfcAdmin so you can hook into both if you want to.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of both Ensemble and ZfcAdmin*

With regard to the configuration of ZfcAdmin, you should definitely start with the documentation. It's provided in the [repository of ZfcAdmin](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/blob/master/docs/1.Introduction.md). There is also a single page document about [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize#bjyauthorize---acl-security-for-zf2) how to configure the module.

If you are not familiar with ZF2 and modules of ZF2 in general, I suggest to follow the [user guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) first.

Comment: Thnx , I will take a look at ensemble. As a matter of fact I don't have problem in configuring zfcadmin , What I'm looking for is set all needed configuration in my news module , no additional change in other module . Just copy my news module folder in module folder and every thing take effect .